# How can I extract EDB (ms exchange storage file) to PST Under Linux? (preferably in Python)

Tags: python, linux, exchange-server, extract, pst

I can extract and read messages from PST files using libpst , but i want to extract from edb files too (not online exchange server but from offline files). And in Linux.

Any python lib or any kind for linux commandline tool should help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Joachim Metz' work. He reverse engineered the edb format and analyzed the exchange database to a limited extend. It's open source and there's even some documentation about the tables and columns:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libesedb/files/

However it doesn't create a PST or anything similar. It merely extracts all tables into separate files and tries to decode some of the data. In order to extract the Emails from your EDB file you need to get into the documentation and do plenty of coding as the data is rather scattered around within the databse (of course it just looks like scattered. Microsoft definitely didn't just want to make the lifes of the reverse engineers miserable).

Good luck

Comment: This webpage is not available anymore, the project seems to be moved to https://github.com/libyal/libesedb